# ksqldb REST API - how to receive tombstone values from tables with push queries?

Tags: ksqldb

How is it possible to receive tombstone values with **ksqldb REST API**?

Table example:

```
CREATE TABLE movies (
      title VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY,
      id INT,
      release_year INT
    ) WITH (
      KAFKA_TOPIC='movies',
      PARTITIONS=1,
      VALUE_FORMAT = 'JSON'
    );

INSERT INTO MOVIES (ID, TITLE, RELEASE_YEAR) VALUES (48, 'Aliens', 1986);
```

Robin. M. [posted a workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66305527/how-to-delete-a-value-from-ksqldb-table-or-insert-a-tombstone-value/66314510#66314510) how to insert tombstone values into a table.

The following ksql query via REST API does not receive those "deleted" values:

```
POST /query HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/vnd.ksql.v1+json
Content-Type: application/vnd.ksql.v1+json

{"ksql":"SELECT * FROM Movies EMIT CHANGES;","streamsProperties":{"ksql.streams.auto.offset.reset":"earliest"}}
```

Row insert received example:

```
[{"header":{"queryId":"none","schema":"`TITLE` STRING, `ID` INTEGER, `RELEASE_YEAR` INTEGER"}},
{"row":{"columns":["Die Hard",2,1998]}},
```

Expected [response](https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/developer-guide/ksqldb-rest-api/query-endpoint/#example-table-response) after inserting a tombstone value is a row with boolean row.tombstone property:

```
{"row":{"columns":["Die Hard",null,null],"tombstone":true}}
```

The value is not sent to the clients. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong? In case it is possible to receive these values, can I do the same with /query-stream API?

Answer (score 0):

I found this [issue](https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/6438) on GitHub, so I tried the recently released version 0.15.0 and it works. So it seems it is a bug in v0.14.0.